# Problem with "Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by Border Following" by Suzuki Abe

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a Problem with the Paper "Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by Border Following" by Suzuki and Abe. In the Chapter "Appendix I: The Formal Description of Algorithm 1" i might find some issues:

If we use the the Algorithm to detect the boardes and the tropolical Sturcture of the following picture.

[image: binary image1]

So we start to find the first not zero Pixel and decide it is a startpoint for an outerboarder. If we follow the Algorithm in the paper, it should looks like this after the detection of the outer boarder.

[image: binary Image2]

But if it looks like this one, we will never found the holeboarder, because the holeboardre starting point is defined as the value f of the pixel (i,j) has to be higher then 1 and the value of the pixel (i,j+1) has to be 0.

In my opinion the step 3.3 ist wrong, if you compare the algorithm to the pictures in the paper.

Comment: This is an interesting question but you likely won’t find a good answer here. Try asking on an image processing stack exchange site

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same result, will dig into it more and see if I can figure out what's going on.  No wonder no source code following this paper works.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered the issue, it was explained with an example here: [dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/84045/problem-with-topological-structural-analysis-of-digitized-binary-images-by-bord?newreg=58b580277bde4778aae61405455e430b).

The issue comes from the interpretation of the (3.4)(a) and (3.4)(b) parts.  It is not asking to check if the Eastern pixel is a non-zero or zero value, it is only referring to the fact if it was looked at in (3.3).  The value does not matter, so don't check the value but instead follow the directions based on whether or not that pixel was examined in step 3.3.

I have seen many code examples online for this algorithm and they are all incorrect (except for OpenCV).  Once I have a decent example I may post the code so that at least we have a proper example to go off of moving forward.